# Watch OS simulator not loading, getting "DYLD_ROOT_PATH not set for simulator" error

Tags: ios, swift, watchos, ios15, watchos-simulator

I have having a strange issue while adding watch app target in my existing project. After adding watch app as target in my app, when I try to load watch app simulator , it simply crashes & only one line error is displayed as **"dyld[14574]: DYLD_ROOT_PATH not set for simulator program"** ..

I have added screenshot for same below. Moreover the problem only occurs with my current project in which I have added new watch app as target, simulator is loading fine when watch app is added to other projects. I am not able to figure out what specific thing is causing this issue in my existing project.

Xcode: 13.3, OS: MacOS Monterey, v12.1

[image]

Comment: Hey did you manage to fix the issue?

Answer (score -1):

you may want to double check on "Other linker flags" in project settings.